# Websphere WCT Crashing

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-portal

I'm using Websphere 8.5.5 in REHL-7. I'm trying to launch websphere customization tool box using /wct.sh script from command line, but getting below error :

```
    JVM terminated. Exit code=160
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Toolbox/WCT//../java/jre/bin/javaw
-Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/bootstrap.jar
-Declipse.refreshBundles=true
-jar /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Toolbox/WCT//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash
-launcher /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Toolbox/WCT/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Toolbox/WCT/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101019_1345/eclipse_1310.so
-startup /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Toolbox/WCT//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
-exitdata a70008
-vm /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Toolbox/WCT//../java/jre/bin/javaw
-vmargs
-Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/bootstrap.jar
-Declipse.refreshBundles=true
-jar /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Toolbox/WCT//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
```

Also here is the dump file :

```
0SECTION       TITLE subcomponent dump routine
NULL           ===============================
1TICHARSET     UTF-8
1TISIGINFO     Dump Event "gpf" (00002000) received 
1TIDATETIME    Date:                 2019/01/13 at 17:30:01
1TIFILENAME    Javacore filename:    /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Toolbox/WCT/javacore.20190113.173000.25196.0002.txt
1TIREQFLAGS    Request Flags: 0x81 (exclusive+preempt)
1TIPREPSTATE   Prep State: 0x100 (trace_disabled)
1TIPREPINFO    Exclusive VM access not taken: data may not be consistent across javacore sections
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       GPINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           ================================
2XHOSLEVEL     OS Level         : Linux 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64
2XHCPUS        Processors -
3XHCPUARCH       Architecture   : x86
3XHNUMCPUS       How Many       : 2
3XHNUMASUP       NUMA is either not supported or has been disabled by user
NULL           
1XHEXCPCODE    J9Generic_Signal_Number: 00000004
1XHEXCPCODE    Signal_Number: 0000000B
1XHEXCPCODE    Error_Value: 00000000
1XHEXCPCODE    Signal_Code: 00000080
1XHEXCPCODE    Handler1: F6A87DBA
1XHEXCPCODE    Handler2: F6C3E277
1XHEXCPCODE    InaccessibleAddress: 00000000
NULL           
1XHEXCPMODULE  Module: /lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
1XHEXCPMODULE  Module_base_address: D3229000
```

Can anyone help to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

So it is a problem with your linux modules either xulrunner see here https://learnergene.blogspot.com/2015/08/jvm-terminated-exit-code160.html . or if you look at libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0